# NetworkInfo Reflection

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to reflect a constructor of `NetworkInfo` described [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/net/NetworkInfo.java#NetworkInfo.%3Cinit%3E%28int,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29).

So far i have

```
    NetworkInfo mNetworkInfo;
    Class<NetworkInfo> clazz = NetworkInfo.class;
    Constructor<NetworkInfo> con = clazz.getConstructor(int.class,int.class,String.class,String.class);
    mNetworkInfo = con.newInstance(n1,n2,s1,s2);
```

However i keep getting a `NoSuchMethodException` error. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: And what you want to achieve? Reflection is not recommended if there is another way how to achieve something in "cleaner way"

Comment: I'm trying to unit test a class that uses `ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()` which returns a `NetworkInfo` object. I want to replace this with mNetworkInfo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the the `getConstructor` correctly. I think you just don't have compatible versions of android SDK.

The javadoc for [`NetworkInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) doesn't show any constructors.

Are you running your code on a device that is running version `4.2.2_r1`?

Comment: My minimum sdk version is 8. From what i can see in Grepcode this constructor has been present since API 3.

Comment: @RaickyDerwent API level 8 (Froyo) is android version 2.2.x. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels). The Constructor doesn't seem to exist in that version.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I was refering to [this doc](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/net/NetworkInfo.java#NetworkInfo.%3Cinit%3E%28int%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) that says that the constructor was present pre 2.2.x. I couldn't find any info regarding this on the dev.android site.

Comment: @Raicky You can go through all of them if you want, [this one doesn't have it](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/net/NetworkInfo.java?av=f). Change your API level.

Comment: You were right! I didn't read your full response before typing out that first comment. It does indeed work on a 4.2 device! Thank you so much!